# Stuck with Android studio

Tags: java, android

I am currently building an app where the user enters their name and when you press the button it should say "Welcome, (whatever name the user entered) in a Toast.

I feel like I have everything write but it's not working. It lets me type in my name but when I click the button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText input;
private Button click;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.outputBTN);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input.getText(). "Welcome ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: What is `input.getText(). "Welcome "` supposed to do? The string concatenation operator in Java is `+`, not `.`. Also, why is this question tagged with javascript?

Comment: 1.How does R.layout.activity_main look like? 2. Is R.id.outputBTN clickable? Is there a typo between getText() and Welcome and you mean `input.getText() + " Welcome"` ?

Comment: "Welcome " + input.getText().toString()

Comment: you don't need `getApplicationContext()` but `getContext()`.

Comment: Ahh okay yes, sorry. I meant to put +. That did help, and I just had to flip welcome and input.getText so it appeared in the right order. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `toString();` method because `input.getText()` returns you an Editable Object!

With the `toString()` you can convert your Object into a String.

See getText() method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Solution:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome," + input.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH.SHORT).show();
```